# Why am I getting the error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()" on my plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been stuck on this for quite a while and I'm not sure how to fix it - here is the code and the error that comes with it:

```
data = data.sort_values(by=['Happiness Rank'])

plt.figure(figsize=(20,13))
sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='Happiness Score',y='Economy (GDP per Capita)', hue = 'Year')
plt.title('Life Satisfication vs GDP per Capita',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Life Satisfication',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('GDP per Capita',fontsize=16)
for i in range(len(data)):
    plt.text(s=data.loc[i,'Country'], x=data.loc[i,'Happiness Score']+0.01,
             y=data.loc[i,'Economy (GDP per Capita)']+0.01, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

This code prints out the scatterplot with points but doesn't have the country names next to the points, which is where the error comes in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-c451b5b6b763> in <module>
      5 plt.ylabel('GDP per Capita',fontsize=16)
      6 for i in range(len(data)):
----> 7     plt.text(s=(data.loc[i,'Country']), x=(data.loc[i,'Happiness Score']+0.01),
      8              y=(data.loc[i,'Economy (GDP per Capita)']+0.01), fontsize=10)
      9 plt.show()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in text(x, y, s, fontdict, **kwargs)
   3007 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.text)
   3008 def text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs):
-> 3009     return gca().text(x, y, s, fontdict=fontdict, **kwargs)
   3010 
   3011 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in text(self, x, y, s, fontdict, **kwargs)
    763             **kwargs,
    764         }
--> 765         t = mtext.Text(x, y, text=s, **effective_kwargs)
    766         t.set_clip_path(self.patch)
    767         self._add_text(t)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in __init__(self, x, y, text, color, verticalalignment, horizontalalignment, multialignment, fontproperties, rotation, linespacing, rotation_mode, usetex, wrap, **kwargs)
    149         self._x, self._y = x, y
    150         self._text = ''
--> 151         self.set_text(text)
    152         self.set_color(color if color is not None else rcParams["text.color"])
    153         self.set_fontproperties(fontproperties)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in set_text(self, s)
   1163         if s is None:
   1164             s = ''
-> 1165         if s != self._text:
   1166             self._text = str(s)
   1167             self.stale = True

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1440     @final
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1442         raise ValueError(
   1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone knows how to fix this/can explain why this is happening so I can avoid things like this in the future. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This error means that the extraction condition is ambiguous in pandas, so it cannot be extracted, so if there are duplicate indexes, for example, a similar error will occur. If you have data that can be published or a link that can be referenced, please publish it. I'm sure someone will be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like you expected that the index had consecutive values, starting from *0*.

But most likely your DataFrame has the index with **repeating** values.
In such case, *loc[i,…]* retrieves **all** rows with the index of *i*
and from them returns the particular column.
The type of such returned value is a *Series* not a "single" value.

One of ways to circumvent this problem is to iterate over rows,
e.g. using *iterrows*. Then you can actually ignore index values
and retrieve only columns of interest from the current row.

So change your loop to something like:

```
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    plt.text(s=row['Country'], x=row['Happiness Score']+0.01,
        y=row['Economy (GDP per Capita)']+0.01, fontsize=10)
```

"_" in the above code is needed as a placeholder to capture the index
of the current row and *row* is actually a *Series* holding the
current row.

Then *row[…]* retrieves the content of partucular column from the
current row.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `loc`. You can use it in a loop, but not in this situation. Google "Plotly". It's easier to make plots in Plotly.